# converting excel sumifs formula to vba code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I'm trying to do a SUMIFS calculation in VBA. It works fine when I enter it on the spreadsheet, but when I try to convert it to VBA, it doesn't seem to work.

```
Sheets("Master").Range("B2:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = _
    "=SUMIFS(Input!C32,Input!C37,Master!C1,Input!C31,Master!R1C)"
```

This is the snippet of code (originally in a comment):

```
Dim LastRow As Long 
Dim rw As Long 
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 
For rw = 2 To LastRow 
  Sheets("Master").Cells(rw, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Input").Range("AF:AF"), Sheets("Input").Range("AK:AK"), Sheets("Master").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Input").Range("AE:AE").Sheets("Master").Range("B2"))  
Next
```

Comment: Seek and ye shall [FIND](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+sumifs)

Comment: What "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: i am trying to run this code Dim LastRow As Long

   Dim rw As Long



LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For rw = 2 To LastRow

    Sheets("Master").Cells(rw, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("Input").Range("AF:AF"), Sheets("Input").Range("AK:AK"), Sheets("Master").Range("A:A"), Sheets("Input").Range("AE:AE").Sheets("Master").Range("B2"))

            Next

Comment: Add the code that isn't working to your question rather than a comment.

Comment: and additional tip: you set formula in R1C1 syntax while assigning it to `.Formula` properties. Try to change `.Formula` into `.FormulaR1C1`

Comment: @KazJaw: good edit. The question is much easier to understand now.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't specifying the values you want to lookup in your criteria1. You have to specify a value, not a range.

Your sum range is fine.

```
Sheets("Input").Range("AF:AF")
```

Your criteria range1 is fine.

```
Sheets("Input").Range("AK:AK")
```

Your criteria1 needs to be a value, not a range.

Use this `Sheets("Master").Range("A2").value`
instead of `Sheets("Master").Range("A:A")`

Obviously you can replace the 2 in the criteria1 with a variable if you need to to get your loop to work.